# VB .NET - Length of the data to decrypt is invalid

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I'm trying to do an exercise about encryption and decryption. I already have the following working code to encrypt (I know that ECB is bad, I won't use it in real life, I promise):

```
Dim hashmd5 As MD5CryptoServiceProvider
Dim des As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
Dim keyhash As Byte()
Dim buff As Byte()

Try

   hashmd5 = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
   keyhash = hashmd5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("exe67rci89"))

   des = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
   des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
   des.Key = keyhash
   buff = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Me.txtPwd.Text)

   Me.txtPwd.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(des.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length))

Catch ex As System.Exception
   Throw ex
End Try
```

Now I'm trying to decrypt the output of this function. I tried to use the same code, just substituting the encryption line with:

```
Me.txtPwd.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(des.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length))
```

But it doesn't work, because I receive the error "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid". I already tried many solutions found here on stack overflow, but no one works. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not reversing enough of the transformation. What's now in `txtPwd` is a base-64 string, not a plain string to be converted using the ASCII encoding. And conversely, what you're going to *produce* in decryption are bytes that should be interpreted as ASCII characters.

So what you want is:

```
buff = Convert.FromBase64String(Me.txtPwd.Text)

Me.txtPwd.Text = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(des.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to decrypted isn't exactly the same as what came out of the actual encrypt:

In your encrypt you convert the encrypted bytes to a base 64 string using `Convert.ToBase64String`

You need to convert the string in the txtPwd field back into the byte array that was the result of the original encryption. See the matching `Convert.FromBase64String` method.

You might be able to view what I mean better if you split the original encrypt line up:

```
dim encBytes = des.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length)
Me.txtPwd.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encBytes)
```

This way you can see the actual encrypt results, and validate that what you pass in is the same.